# How to bind properties both ways WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I am a reeeally noob beginner WPF developer, and getting the hang of c#.
I am creating an app, where I need a knob Button and a TextBox Display, where the knob adjusts the text from the display, and the display, if text is changed, updates the knob position.

[Inage example of my application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Ndiy.jpg)

I've managed to create the Knob Button, which spins when clicked and dragged, and also managed to bind it's value to the TextBox, it displays the value perfectly, but I can't make the TextBox Text update the Knob's position, which is defined by Angle variable (from the RotateTransform thing), the code is as follows:

```
<UserControl x:Class="quaselaeuespero.VolumeControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:quaselaeuespero"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="154" d:DesignWidth="148">
    <Grid>
        <Image Name="aPorradoknob" Source="Knob.png" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
            <Image.RenderTransform>
                <RotateTransform Angle="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:VolumeControl}}, Path=Angle}"/>
            </Image.RenderTransform>
        </Image>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace quaselaeuespero
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for VolumeControl.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class VolumeControl : UserControl
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty AngleProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Angle", typeof(double), typeof(VolumeControl), new UIPropertyMetadata(0.0));
        public double Angle
        {
            get { return (double)GetValue(AngleProperty); }
            set { SetValue(AngleProperty, value);  }
        }

        public VolumeControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Angle = 120;
            this.MouseLeftButtonDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(OnMouseLeftButtonDown);
            this.MouseUp += new MouseButtonEventHandler(OnMouseUp);
            this.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(OnMouseMove);
        }

        private void OnMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            Mouse.Capture(this);
        }

        private void OnMouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            Mouse.Capture(null);
        }

        private void OnMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Mouse.Captured == this)
            {
                // Get the current mouse position relative to the volume control
                Point currentLocation = Mouse.GetPosition(this);

                // We want to rotate around the center of the knob, not the top corner
                Point knobCenter = new Point(this.ActualHeight / 2, this.ActualWidth / 2);

                // Calculate an angle
                double radians = Math.Atan((currentLocation.Y - knobCenter.Y) /
                                           (currentLocation.X - knobCenter.X));
                this.Angle = radians * 180 / Math.PI;

                // Apply a 180 degree shift when X is negative so that we can rotate
                // all of the way around
                if (currentLocation.X - knobCenter.X < 0)
                {
                    this.Angle += 180;
                }

                if(this.Angle >= -90 && this.Angle <= -45)
                {
                    this.Angle = 270;
                }

                if (this.Angle >= -45 && this.Angle <= 0)
                {
                    this.Angle = 1;
                }
                this.Angle = Math.Round(this.Angle, 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The Knob is `<VolumeControl/>` and Display is `<DisplayBPM/>`, in the main Window I tried to bind them both:

```
<Window x:Class="quaselaeuespero.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:quaselaeuespero"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="540" Width="960">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="Background.png"/>
        </Grid.Background>
        <local:VolumeControl x:Name="Knobão" Margin="123,240,675,111" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Angle="{Binding ElementName=BPMDisplay, Path=BPM, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}"/>
        <local:DisplayBPM x:Name="BPMDisplay" BPM="{Binding ElementName=Knobão, Path=Angle, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}" Margin="68,153,656,274" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Grid>


</Window>
```

The following is the code for DisplayBPM:

```
<UserControl x:Class="quaselaeuespero.DisplayBPM"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:quaselaeuespero"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="79
             " d:DesignWidth="229"
             Name="Display">
    <Grid Margin="0">
        <TextBox x:Name="BPMTexto" Text="{Binding ElementName=Display, Path=BPM}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,4,0" Width="222" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" SelectionBrush="{x:Null}" Foreground="#FFCF1D1D" FontSize="80" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" FontFamily="DS-Digital" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" CaretBrush="#FFCF1D1D">
            <TextBox.Background>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="Display BPM.png" Stretch="Uniform"/>
            </TextBox.Background>
        </TextBox>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

and the DisplayBPM.xaml.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace quaselaeuespero
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for DisplayBPM.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class DisplayBPM : UserControl
    {
        private void BPMTexto_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            BPM = Convert.ToDouble(BPMTexto.Text); 
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty BPMProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("BPM", typeof(double), typeof(DisplayBPM), new UIPropertyMetadata(0.0));
        public double BPM
        {
            get { return (double)GetValue(BPMProperty); }
            set { SetValue(BPMProperty, value); }
        }
        public DisplayBPM()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BPM = 1;
        }

        
    }


}
```

The problem is that BPM (variable from DisplayBPM, from which TextBox gets its input) doesn't seem to be changed, and if it is changed, it is not changing Angle (variable from RotateTransform that determines the Knob position). Can anyone help me? I know there are probably tons of basic problems, it would really help me if you could explain them to me. Thank you so much!

Comment: Two-way binding with a `TextBox.Text` property works fine by default. Your posted code is far more complicated than should be necessary to reproduce the specific problem you seem to be asking about. Please read [mcve] to understand how to provide an appropriate code example. See also [ask] for information on how to present your question in a clear, answerable way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start, making a custom user control that has `Dependency Properties` is not the solution for every problem in `WPF`.

`WPF` Apps are primarily architected with `MVVM`: Model - View - ViewModel

With that stated for your specific need I would **keep** the `VolumeControl` as that is the correct way to create custom `UserControls` that have custom `DependencyProperties`

I would then **delete** the `DisplayBPM` class as it is not needed.

I would setup a `ViewModel` to interact between your controls that contains a single `BPM` string property.

Here is an example `ViewModel` I would use:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _bpm;
    public string BPM
    {
        get => _bpm;
        set 
        {
            _bpm = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(BPM));
        }
    }

    public void RaisePropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

> As a side note, I would suggest reading up on `INotifyPropertyChanged`
> as there are many libraries out there that you can use to help with
> `WPF` and `MVVM`

I would then setup the `Window` with the `VolumeControl` and just a `TextBox` to hold the `BPM` value.  Both of these should have a `{Binding BPM, Mode=TwoWay}` so that you pass the `BPM` value between controls.

You can then decide on the `TextBox` binding if you want the value to take as the user is typing or after the user leaves the field (usually with the `Tab` key).  To have the value update the `VolumeControl` as the user is typing have `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` in the binding.

See my example here:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainWindowViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <Grid.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="Background.png"/>
    </Grid.Background>
    <local:VolumeControl
        x:Name="Knobão"
        Margin="123,240,675,111"
        RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"
        Angle="{Binding BPM, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    <TextBox
        Text="{Binding BPM, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
        Margin="68,153,656,274"
        MinWidth="222"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <TextBox.Background>
            <ImageBrush
                ImageSource="Display BPM.png"
                Stretch="Uniform" />
        </TextBox.Background>
    </TextBox>
</Grid>
```

If you are not familiar with how `ViewModels` and `DataContext` work within `WPF` I would recommend reading up on that as that is the primary way to setup an `MVVM` architecture for `WPF` apps.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Actually, when I saw this solution, I kind of had solved the problem, but I actually had to delete DisplayBPM, but I put it's textbox in VolumeControl, so they binded like I wanted them to. But I used TextChangedEvent to make it update, knowing about UpdateSourceTrigger helped me so so much, thank you so so so much chancea!